# regexp match characters into parentheses

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to export via a javascript string values ​​within parentheses ().

example that works:

```
var a = "(test) (a b c)";
alert(a.match(/\([\s\S]+?\)/gi));//output: [(test),(a b c)]
```

But in some older browsers the "?" causes error.

So I did this:

```
var a = "(test) (a b c)";
alert(a.match(/\([A-Za-z0-9\-_\t\r\n\s]+\)/gi));
```

However this way not support foreign characters. Hence the need to use **\S**

I need a solution with **\s\S** and that do not use the **?** signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match non-`)` characters:

```
/\([^)]+\)/
```

Answer (score 1):

This one is more easier

```
"(test) (a b c)".match(/\([^\)]+\)/gi); // output: ["(test)", "(a b c)"]
```

Comment: "i" is not necessary. Yet his example helped me.

Fixed: "(test) (a b c)".match(/\([^\)]+\)/g); Thanks

Comment: Ah, @GuilhermeNascimento I just copy from your example and didn't get rid of it sorry :)

Comment: Truth was I to blame, no need to apologize, it was my fault. I'm sorry and thank you (:

Answer (score 1):

Think this will do it for you, no?

([^)]*)

http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: lacked the "\": Fixed: \\([^)]*\\) , thanks Jim, but I'll use the example of John